# Convert Serialized Django Model Instance Back to Object in Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm using Ajax to search for a model instance, return that instance, and pass it as a variable to a template tag in my template. In my view, I serialize the object before sending it to the Ajax success function. Once I'm back in my Ajax function, though, how do I get it back to being a model instance so I can use it in my template?

template.html

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" style="border: 2px solid #e4e4e4; border-radius: 8px">
                <p class="text-center" style="color: #27AE60; padding: 20px 20px 0px 20px"><b>Generate the citation for a desired dataset by typing its ID number in the box below:</b></p>
                <form role="form" method="get" action="{% url 'databank:get_citation' %}" id="citation-form" style="padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon" id="doi-prefix">11.23/</span>
                    <input type="Search" placeholder="Data ID" class="form-control form-search2" id="data-id" name="q">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                      <button class="btn blue-search-button">
                         <span>Go</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="results">{{ errors }}</div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="generatedCitation">
                        <p style='font-size: 20px'class="citationResults">{% include 'databank/includes/citation.html' with dataset=citationdataset registration=citationregistration %}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

main.js

```
$('#citation-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
    get_citation();
});

function get_citation(){
    console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
    $.ajax({
        url : "get_citation/", // the endpoint
        type : "GET", // http method
        data : { data_id : $('#data-id').val() }, // data sent with the get request

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(json) {
            $('#data-id').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
            if(json.errors){
              $('.errors').html(json.errors);
            }
            else{
              $('.citationResults').html(json.citation.citationdataset);
              $('.citationResults').html(json.registration.citationregistration);
            }
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

views.py

```
def get_citation(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        dataset_id = request.GET.get('data_id')
        print "ID IS: ", dataset_id

        try:
            dataset = Dataset.objects.get(dataset_id=dataset_id)
            registration = Registration.objects.get(dataset=dataset)
            if dataset.status == 'public':
                print "PUBLIC: ", dataset, registration
                data_info = {}
                dataset = serializers.serialize('json', [ dataset, ])
                data_info['dataset'] = dataset
                registration = serializers.serialize('json', [ registration, ])
                data_info['registration'] =  registration
                return JsonResponse(data_info)

            else:
                return JsonResponse({"errors": "The dataset you requested has not yet been made public. Check back later."})

        except Dataset.DoesNotExist:
            return JsonResponse({"errors": "The dataset you requested could not be found. Make sure you are using the correct ID."})
```

---

New Working, Code after Following @JulienGrégoire 's advice-

template.html:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <p><b>Citation Generator</b></p>
            <form role="form" method="get" action="{% url 'databank:get_citation' %}" id="citation-form">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon" id="doi-prefix">11.0/</span>
                <input type="Search" placeholder="Data ID" class="form-control form-search2" id="data-id" name="q">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn blue-search-button">
                     <span>Get Citation</span>
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1" id="generatedCitation">
                    <p style='font-size: 20px' class="citationResults"></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

main.js:

```
$('#citation-form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("citation generator form submitted") 
    get_citation();
});

function get_citation(){
    console.log("citation generator is working!")
    $.ajax({
        url : "get_citation/", 
        type : "GET", 
        data : { data_id : $('#data-id').val() }, // data sent with the get request, the inputted data id

        // handle a successful response
        success : function(data) {
            $('#data-id').val(''); // remove the value from the input
            console.log(data); // log the returned json to the console
            $('.citationResults').html(data);
            console.log("success"); // another sanity check
        },

        // handle a non-successful response
        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            $('.citationResults').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
                " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
        }
    });
};
```

views.py:

```
def get_citation(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        dataset_id = request.GET.get('data_id')

        try:
            dataset = Dataset.objects.get(dataset_id=dataset_id)
            registration = Registration.objects.get(dataset=dataset)
            if dataset.status == 'public':
                context = {'registration': registration, 'dataset': dataset}
                html = render_to_string('databank/includes/citation.html', context)
                return HttpResponse(html)

            else:
                context = {'message': "The dataset you requested has not yet been made public. Check back later."}
                html = render_to_string('databank/includes/no_citation.html', context)
                return HttpResponse(html)

        except Dataset.DoesNotExist:
            context = {'message': "The dataset you requested could not be found. Make sure you are using a valid ID."}
            html = render_to_string('databank/includes/no_citation.html', context)
            return HttpResponse(html)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templates are rendered on server, so I don't see how you can render it in javascript, which is client side.

What you can do is create a template that only takes care of the portion you want to update and send rendered html from your view and reinject it.

So here, instead of serializing in your view, you would return a render with appropriate context and template and use your jquery html function to insert it and your div and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @juliengregoire! I updated my question with the new, working code.